# Installing/emulating SLURM on an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop: slurmd fails to start

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, slurm

## Edit

What I am really looking for is a way to emulate SLURM, something interactive and reasonably user-friendly that I can install.

---

## Original post

I want to test drive some minimal examples with SLURM, and I am trying to install it all on a local machine with Ubuntu 16.04. I am following [the most recent slurm install guide I could find](https://github.com/superphy/semantic/wiki/SLURM-install-guide), and I got as far as "start `slurmd` with `sudo /etc/init.d/slurmd start`".

```
[....] Starting slurmd (via systemctl): slurmd.serviceJob for slurmd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status slurmd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

I do not know how to interpret the `systemctl` log:

```
● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-10-26 22:49:27 EDT; 12s ago
  Process: 5951 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 26 22:49:27 Haggunenon systemd[1]: Starting Slurm node daemon...
Oct 26 22:49:27 Haggunenon systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 26 22:49:27 Haggunenon systemd[1]: Failed to start Slurm node daemon.
Oct 26 22:49:27 Haggunenon systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 26 22:49:27 Haggunenon systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

`lsb_release -a` gives the following. (Yes, I know, KDE Neon is not exactly Ubuntu, strictly speaking.)

```
o LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: neon
Description:    KDE neon User Edition 5.11
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Unlike the guide said, I used my own user name, `wlandau`, and I made sure to `chown` `/var/lib/slurm-llnl` and `/var/run/slurm-llnl` to me. Here is my `/etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf`.

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ControlMachine=linux0
#ControlAddr=
#BackupController=
#BackupAddr=
#
AuthType=auth/munge
CacheGroups=0
#CheckpointType=checkpoint/none
CryptoType=crypto/munge
#DisableRootJobs=NO
#EnforcePartLimits=NO
#Epilog=
#EpilogSlurmctld=
#FirstJobId=1
#MaxJobId=999999
#GresTypes=
#GroupUpdateForce=0
#GroupUpdateTime=600
#JobCheckpointDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/checkpoint
#JobCredentialPrivateKey=
#JobCredentialPublicCertificate=
#JobFileAppend=0
#JobRequeue=1
#JobSubmitPlugins=1
#KillOnBadExit=0
#LaunchType=launch/slurm
#Licenses=foo*4,bar
#MailProg=/usr/bin/mail
#MaxJobCount=5000
#MaxStepCount=40000
#MaxTasksPerNode=128
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-#
#PluginDir=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PrivateData=jobs
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
#Prolog=
#PrologFlags=
#PrologSlurmctld=
#PropagatePrioProcess=0
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
#RebootProgram=
ReturnToService=1
#SallocDefaultCommand=
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=wlandau
#SlurmdUser=root
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/none
#TaskPluginParam=
#TaskProlog=
#TopologyPlugin=topology/tree
#TmpFS=/tmp
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=
#UnkillableStepProgram=
#UsePAM=0
#
#
# TIMERS
#BatchStartTimeout=10
#CompleteWait=0
#EpilogMsgTime=2000
#GetEnvTimeout=2
#HealthCheckInterval=0
#HealthCheckProgram=
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
#MessageTimeout=10
#ResvOverRun=0
MinJobAge=300
#OverTimeLimit=0
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
#UnkillableStepTimeout=60
#VSizeFactor=0
Waittime=0
#
#
# SCHEDULING
#DefMemPerCPU=0
FastSchedule=1
#MaxMemPerCPU=0
#SchedulerRootFilter=1
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SchedulerPort=7321
SelectType=select/linear
#SelectTypeParameters=
#
#
# JOB PRIORITY
#PriorityFlags=
#PriorityType=priority/basic
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=
#PriorityCalcPeriod=
#PriorityFavorSmall=
#PriorityMaxAge=
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=
#PriorityWeightAge=
#PriorityWeightFairshare=
#PriorityWeightJobSize=
#PriorityWeightPartition=
#PriorityWeightQOS=
#
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
#AccountingStorageEnforce=0
#AccountingStorageHost=
#AccountingStorageLoc=
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
#AccountingStorageUser=
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
#DebugFlags=
#JobCompHost=
#JobCompLoc=
#JobCompPass=
#JobCompPort=
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#JobCompUser=
#JobContainerPlugin=job_container/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#SlurmSchedLogFile=
#SlurmSchedLogLevel=
#
#
# POWER SAVE SUPPORT FOR IDLE NODES (optional)
#SuspendProgram=
#ResumeProgram=
#SuspendTimeout=
#ResumeTimeout=
#ResumeRate=
#SuspendExcNodes=
#SuspendExcParts=
#SuspendRate=
#SuspendTime=
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=linux[1-32] CPUs=1 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=linux[1-32] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

## Follow-up

After rewriting my `slurm.conf` with the help of @damienfrancois, `slurmd` starts now. But unfortunately, `sinfo` hangs when I call it, and I get the same error message as before.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/slurmctld stop
[ ok ] Stopping slurmctld (via systemctl): slurmctld.service.
$ sudo /etc/init.d/slurmctld start
[ ok ] Starting slurmctld (via systemctl): slurmctld.service.
$ sinfo
slurm_load_partitions: Unable to contact slurm controller (connect failure)
$ slurmd -Dvvv
slurmd: fatal: Frontend not configured correctly in slurm.conf.  See man slurm.conf look for frontendname.
```

Then I tried restarting the daemons, and `slurmd` failed to start all over again.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/slurmctld start
[....] Starting slurmd (via systemctl): slurmd.serviceJob for slurmd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status slurmd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

Comment: Just to be sure, `slurmd` must run as root on the compute nodes. `slurmctld` must run as a regular user on the head node

Comment: Just tried `sudo su; /etc/init.d/slurmd start` and got the same failure.

Comment: what is the name of the computer on which you run that command?

Comment: The computer's name itself is `Haggunenon`. Does that need to be in the config file somewhere?

Comment: `slurmd` must only run on one of the linux[1-32] nodes

Comment: and slurmctld onlinux0

Comment: Could the trouble be that I have a desktop computer with only one CPU? Is there still any way to run both `slurmd` and `slurmctld`? It would be great if you could spell it out for me.

Comment: Try first running it in the foreground in debug mode and look at the exact reason why it stops: `slurmd -Dvvv`

Comment: I get `slurmd: fatal: Frontend not configured correctly in slurm.conf.  See man slurm.conf look for frontendname.`

Comment: I vaguely recall an issue betwene the basic Debian package -- which gets ported here unaltered -- running into an issue because a `/var` subdirectory does _not_ have write perms here on Ubuntu whereas it has for Debian.  If you google hard you may find old posts of mine on this.  Of course, it could be something entirely different too for you here...

Comment: Good thing to check. `ls -l` does show write permissions for me in `/var/log/slurm-llnl`, `/var/run/slurm-llnl`, and `/var/lib/slurm-llnl`.

Comment: What I really think I need is guidance on how to set up `slurm.conf`. All the documentation I can find assumes the host and the compute nodes are different, but they are the all the same in my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value in front of `ControlMachine` has to match the output of `hostname -s` on the machine on which `slurmctld` starts. The same holds for `NodeName` ; it has to match the output of `hostname -s` on the machine on which `slurmd` starts. As you only have one machine and it appears to be called `Haggunenon`, the relevant lines in `slurm.conf` should be:

```
ControlMachine=Haggunenon
[...]
NodeName=Haggunenon CPUs=1 State=UNKNOWN
```

If you want to start several `slurmd` daemon to emulate a larger cluster, you will need to start `slurmd` with the `-N` option (but that requires that Slurm be built using the `--enable-multiple-slurmd` configure option)

---

UPDATE. Here is a walkthrough. I setup a VM with Vagrant and VirtualBox (`vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64 ; vagrant up`) and then after `vagrant ssh`, I ran the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
[...]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [3,060 B]
Fetched 23.6 MB in 4s (4,783 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo apt-get install munge libmunge2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmunge2 munge
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 102 kB of archives.
After this operation, 351 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 libmunge2 amd64 0.5.11-3ubuntu0.1 [18.4 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 munge amd64 0.5.11-3ubuntu0.1 [83.9 kB]
Fetched 102 kB in 0s (290 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libmunge2.
(Reading database ... 57914 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmunge2_0.5.11-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmunge2 (0.5.11-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package munge.
Preparing to unpack .../munge_0.5.11-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking munge (0.5.11-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up libmunge2 (0.5.11-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up munge (0.5.11-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Generating a pseudo-random key using /dev/urandom completed.
Please refer to /usr/share/doc/munge/README.Debian for instructions to generate more secure key.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo apt-get install slurm-wlm slurm-wlm-basic-plugins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core freeipmi-common libcairo2 libdatrie1 libdbi1 libfontconfig1 libfreeipmi16 libgraphite2-3 
[...]
  python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal slurm-client slurm-wlm slurm-wlm-basic-plugins slurmctld slurmd
0 upgraded, 43 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 20.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 fonts-dejavu-core all 2.35-1 [1,039 kB]
[...]
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 slurm-wlm amd64 15.08.7-1build1 [6,482 B]
Fetched 20.8 MB in 3s (5,274 kB/s)
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-dejavu-core.
(Reading database ... 57952 files and directories currently installed.)
[...]
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo vim /etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ grep -v \# /etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf
ControlMachine=ubuntu-xenial
AuthType=auth/munge
CacheGroups=0
CryptoType=crypto/munge
MpiDefault=none
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=ubuntu
StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/none
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
MinJobAge=300
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
Waittime=0
FastSchedule=1
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SchedulerPort=7321
SelectType=select/linear
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
NodeName=ubuntu-xenial CPUs=1 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ubuntu-xenial Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo chown ubuntu /var/log/slurm-llnl
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo chown ubuntu /var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo chown ubuntu /var/run/slurm-llnl
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/slurmctld start
[ ok ] Starting slurmctld (via systemctl): slurmctld.service.
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/slurmd start
[ ok ] Starting slurmd (via systemctl): slurmd.service.
```

And in the end, it gives me the expected result:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
debug*       up   infinite      1   idle ubuntu-denial
```

If following the exact steps here does not help, try running:

```
sudo slurmctld -Dvvv
sudo slurmd -Dvvv
```

The messages should be explicit enough.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. [I successfully installed SLURM on a Debian 9.2 VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002755/emulating-slurm-on-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment80953277_47002755) with that exact approach. Unfortunately, it does not work natively on my Ubuntu 16.04 installation.

Comment: Do you still have the `fatal: Frontend not configured correctly in slurm.conf.` message?

Comment: Yes, it persists on my real Ubuntu 16.04 machine, but not my Debian 9.2 VM.

Comment: what is the exact output of `hostname -s` on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: `hostname -s` outputs `Haggunenon`

Comment: @landau I updated my answer with a work through. Does that help?

Comment: sorry, I did not see your edit. I will try your `slurm.conf` tonight, replacing your VM's host and user name with my own. I may have goofed by setting `CPUs=4` in other attempts. (My desktop has a core i5 7600 with 4 cores, and the node may need to think it has its own private resources separate from the host). We will see. Thankfully, I only need 1 node.

Comment: see my follow-up at the bottom of the post. `slurmd` started once, but then the same failures started happening again.

Comment: By the way, is there a need to call `sudo sudo` as above rather than just `sudo`?

Comment: Just  `sudo` is sufficient. Copy/paste mistake

Comment: which version of Slurm are you running? `scontrol version`

Comment: weird, I did the exact same thing in a Vagrant kde-neon box and it succeeded.

Comment: I do check that the relevant `/var` subdirectories have owner `wlandau`. But at one point, I set the permissions really high, thinking that will make it doubly safe. Could it be that high permissions are interfering? What folders would I have to delete to try a completely fresh installation from scratch?

Comment: +damienfrancois I recently had to reinstall my OS (for other reasons), and when I tried this from the start, it worked!

Comment: Should I compile slurm with `--enable-front-end` fiag in order to emulate a larger cluster?

Comment: @alper According to the current version of the FAQ (https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html, question _Can Slurm emulate a larger cluster?_), it appears so