# Emulating SLURM on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, docker, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, slurm

I want to emulate SLURM on Ubuntu 16.04. I don't need serious resource management, I just want to test some simple examples. I [cannot install SLURM in the usual way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966876/installing-emulating-slurm-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-desktop-slurmd-fails-to-start), and I am wondering if there are other options. Other things I have tried:

- A [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/agaveapi/slurm/). Unfortunately, `docker pull agaveapi/slurm; docker run agaveapi/slurm` gives me errors:

  /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supervisor/options.py:295: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
    'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
  2017-10-29 15:27:45,436 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
  2017-10-29 15:27:45,437 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
  2017-10-29 15:27:46,439 INFO spawned: 'slurmd' with pid 9
  2017-10-29 15:27:46,441 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 10
  2017-10-29 15:27:46,443 INFO spawned: 'munge' with pid 11
  2017-10-29 15:27:46,443 INFO spawned: 'slurmctld' with pid 12
  2017-10-29 15:27:46,452 INFO exited: munge (exit status 0; not expected)
  2017-10-29 15:27:46,452 CRIT reaped unknown pid 13)
  2017-10-29 15:27:46,530 INFO gave up: munge entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
  2017-10-29 15:27:46,531 INFO exited: slurmd (exit status 1; not expected)
  2017-10-29 15:27:46,535 INFO gave up: slurmd entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
  2017-10-29 15:27:46,536 INFO exited: slurmctld (exit status 0; not expected)
  2017-10-29 15:27:47,537 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
  2017-10-29 15:27:47,537 INFO gave up: slurmctld entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
- [This guide to start a SLURM VM via Vagrant](https://mussolblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/setting-up-a-testing-slurm-cluster/). I tried, but copying over my `munge` key timed out.

  sudo scp /etc/munge/munge.key vagrant@server:/home/vagrant/
  ssh: connect to host server port 22: Connection timed out
  lost connection

Comment: Will: I always used it plain up, and liked that.  I haven't looked at your other question -- worst case I sometimes locally rebuillt the slurm packages.  I would recommend leaning on the Debian / Ubuntu resources.  I may be able to help you off-line, but I am current traveling.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. It would certainly be best to use SLURM natively if it will install. Do you know of any guides to set up a `slurm.conf` that lets the host machine also be a worker node?

Comment: I'll copy and paste tomorrow when back at work. It is pretty straightforward as I recall but it has been while. The deb package has a helper script too...

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695348/running-multiple-worker-daemons-slurm. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ... we have an existing cluster here but it runs an older Ubuntu version which does not mesh well with my workstation running 17.04.

So on my workstation, I just made sure I `slurmctld` (backend) and `slurmd` installed, and then set up a trivial `slurm.conf` with

```
ControlMachine=mybox
# ...
NodeName=DEFAULT CPUs=4 RealMemory=4000 TmpDisk=50000 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=mybox CPUs=4 RealMemory=16000
```

after which I restarted `slurmcltd` and then `slurmd`.  Now all is fine:

```
root@mybox:/etc/slurm-llnl$ sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
demo         up   infinite      1   idle mybox
root@mybox:/etc/slurm-llnl$
```

This is a degenerate setup, our real one has a mix of dev and prod machine and appropriate partitions.  But this should answer your "can backend really be client" question.  Also, my machine is not really called `mybox` but is not really pertinent for the question in either case.

Using Ubuntu 17.04, all stock, with `munge` to communicate (which is the default anyway).

*Edit*: To wit:

```
me@mybox:~$ COLUMNS=90 dpkg -l '*slurm*' | grep ^ii
ii  slurm-client     16.05.9-1ubun amd64         SLURM client side commands
ii  slurm-wlm-basic- 16.05.9-1ubun amd64         SLURM basic plugins
ii  slurmctld        16.05.9-1ubun amd64         SLURM central management daemon
ii  slurmd           16.05.9-1ubun amd64         SLURM compute node daemon
me@mybox:~$
```

Comment: So it really should work in Ubuntu. This makes me want to try again. Did you install SLURM using `apt-get` or build it yourself? For me, `apt-get` installs 15.08.7, but 16.05.11, 17.02.9 and 17.11.0rc2 can be downloaded.

Comment: I used to locally build (for that aforementioned reason of the directory permissions; this may now be accomodated upstream); what I show above is stock 17.04. See edited answer.

Comment: I just reinstalled my OS (for unrelated reasons), and SLURM actually works this time. I ended up going with Damien Francois' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966876/installing-emulating-slurm-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-desktop-slurmd-fails-to-start).

Answer (score 1):

I would still prefer to run SLURM natively, but I caved and spun up a Debian 9.2 VM. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966876/installing-emulating-slurm-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-desktop-slurmd-fails-to-start/47009930#47009930) for my efforts to troubleshoot a native installation. The [directions here](https://github.com/superphy/semantic/wiki/slurm-install-guide) worked smoothly, but I needed to make the following changes to `slurm.conf`. Below, `Debian64` is the `hostname`, and `wlandau` is my user name.

- `ControlMachine=Debian64`
- `SlurmUser=wlandau`
- `NodeName=Debian64`

Here is the complete `slurm.conf`. An analogous `slurm.conf` did not work on my native Ubuntu 16.04.

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ControlMachine=Debian64
#ControlAddr=
#BackupController=
#BackupAddr=
# 
AuthType=auth/munge
#CheckpointType=checkpoint/none 
CryptoType=crypto/munge
#DisableRootJobs=NO 
#EnforcePartLimits=NO 
#Epilog=
#EpilogSlurmctld= 
#FirstJobId=1 
#MaxJobId=999999 
#GresTypes= 
#GroupUpdateForce=0 
#GroupUpdateTime=600 
#JobCheckpointDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/checkpoint 
#JobCredentialPrivateKey=
#JobCredentialPublicCertificate=
#JobFileAppend=0 
#JobRequeue=1 
#JobSubmitPlugins=1 
#KillOnBadExit=0 
#LaunchType=launch/slurm 
#Licenses=foo*4,bar 
#MailProg=/usr/bin/mail 
#MaxJobCount=5000 
#MaxStepCount=40000 
#MaxTasksPerNode=128 
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-# 
#PluginDir= 
#PlugStackConfig= 
#PrivateData=jobs 
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
#Prolog=
#PrologFlags= 
#PrologSlurmctld= 
#PropagatePrioProcess=0 
#PropagateResourceLimits= 
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept= 
#RebootProgram= 
ReturnToService=1
#SallocDefaultCommand= 
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=wlandau
#SlurmdUser=root 
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/none
#TaskPluginParam=
#TaskProlog=
#TopologyPlugin=topology/tree 
#TmpFS=/tmp 
#TrackWCKey=no 
#TreeWidth= 
#UnkillableStepProgram= 
#UsePAM=0 
# 
# 
# TIMERS 
#BatchStartTimeout=10 
#CompleteWait=0 
#EpilogMsgTime=2000 
#GetEnvTimeout=2 
#HealthCheckInterval=0 
#HealthCheckProgram= 
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
#MessageTimeout=10 
#ResvOverRun=0 
MinJobAge=300
#OverTimeLimit=0 
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
#UnkillableStepTimeout=60 
#VSizeFactor=0 
Waittime=0
# 
# 
# SCHEDULING 
#DefMemPerCPU=0 
FastSchedule=1
#MaxMemPerCPU=0 
#SchedulerRootFilter=1 
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30 
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SchedulerPort=7321
SelectType=select/linear
#SelectTypeParameters=
# 
# 
# JOB PRIORITY 
#PriorityFlags= 
#PriorityType=priority/basic 
#PriorityDecayHalfLife= 
#PriorityCalcPeriod= 
#PriorityFavorSmall= 
#PriorityMaxAge= 
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod= 
#PriorityWeightAge= 
#PriorityWeightFairshare= 
#PriorityWeightJobSize= 
#PriorityWeightPartition= 
#PriorityWeightQOS= 
# 
# 
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING 
#AccountingStorageEnforce=0 
#AccountingStorageHost=
#AccountingStorageLoc=
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
#AccountingStorageUser=
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
#DebugFlags= 
#JobCompHost=
#JobCompLoc=
#JobCompPass=
#JobCompPort=
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#JobCompUser=
#JobContainerType=job_container/none 
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#SlurmSchedLogFile= 
#SlurmSchedLogLevel= 
# 
# 
# POWER SAVE SUPPORT FOR IDLE NODES (optional) 
#SuspendProgram= 
#ResumeProgram= 
#SuspendTimeout= 
#ResumeTimeout= 
#ResumeRate= 
#SuspendExcNodes= 
#SuspendExcParts= 
#SuspendRate= 
#SuspendTime= 
# 
# 
# COMPUTE NODES 
NodeName=Debian64 CPUs=1 RealMemory=744 CoresPerSocket=1 ThreadsPerCore=1 State=UNKNOWN 
PartitionName=debug Nodes=Debian64 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

Comment: I do not see, or cannot tell from what you posted, in which this is different from the default.  As such, this is not all that helpful.  We understand what a username and hostname are.  What else, if anything, needed changing?  What, if anything, would constitute a bug in the package or its documentation and what have you done to communicate that to the package maintainer?

Comment: Hmm... maybe I should have instead emphasized the virtualization instead (VirtualBox and Debian 9.2). Like you said before, there are known SLURM issues on Ubuntu where Debian is unaffected, and that is what I think I experienced. Also, I had a surprising amount of trouble finding explicit setup instructions that allow the host to be the same as a node. In any case, for the Ubuntu issue, I emailed the slurm-dev mailing list earlier in the week, but have not heard back.

Comment: There is no issue with host==client. I had that in all my use cases (mostly on Ubuntu).  Make sure /etc/hosts has your name so that your machine is known by names other than localhost.