# How to set up a cluster for a use in R parallel package

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have several i7 desktops which I would like to use to speed up the computation time of function `genoud` in package `rgenoud`. In `genoud`, you can assign a cluster that was generated in `parallel` (and I assume `snow` also).

What kind of clustering software would you recommend for this? I have tried Beowulf clusters, but the documentation from this is mostly outdated, so I am looking for a guide which shows me how to do it which is still up to date.

This cluster is going to be over LAN, and I have assigned IPs to the nodes.

Thanks

Comment: What OS are these i7 running?  It's pretty easy with Linux: set up ssh authentication and MPI and you're off to the races.  If that is too much, but a Redis db somewhere and use doRedis.  And on and on ...

Comment: Ubuntu. Is there a guide you would recommend for MPI? All of them I could find were extremely outdated and were giving me errors as a result.

Comment: I use Ubuntu too (at work) and have it (had it) set up for slurm. There are / were a few related questions here eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002755/emulating-slurm-on-ubuntu-16-04/) and others by [@landau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3704549/landau).  You could come to the r-sig-hpc too.  One thing to keep in mind is OpenMPI 1.* (older packages) vs 2.* vs 3.* (upstream).

Comment: When using Rmpi, I keep getting the error "MPI_Comm_spawn" is not supported. I read that it had to do with using MPICH, so I installed OpenMPI, but I am still getting the error. Can you help me understand what is wrong? Sorry I am not very knowledgeable about this.

Comment: Rmpi from `r-cran-rmpi` or directly installed?  When do you get the error?  Do you know that MPI requires `mpirun` / `orterun` around scripts and all that?

Comment: When I try to initiate the cluster `makeMPIcluster`, it gives me this error. I thought mpirun/orterun is only when running the MPI from terminal, not R, but I am probably wrong about this. Could you explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Not here, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161553/discussion-between-keshav-m-and-dirk-eddelbuettel).

Comment: No, sorry, I do not the bandwidth for one on one tutorials.

Comment: If of any help, I'm on an up-to-date Ubuntu 16.04 and I never managed to get core Rmpi to work there.  See https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2017-October/002069.html for my call for help on this.

Comment: To your original question: Using a scheduler (e.g. [Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/), [SGE](https://arc.liv.ac.uk/trac/SGE)) is useful and probably a long-term requirement if multiple users use the cluster concurrently.  But you can still get going quickly using an ad-hoc cluster created by `parallel::makeCluster(c("node1", "node2", "node2", "node3"))` as long as R is installed one each node. That does not require MPI. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried this, but it just hangs at makeCluster each time. I left it overnight once and still nothing the next morning. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: Could be firewall issues (need port fwd:ing back to your machine). Try with `cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(c("node1", "node2", "node2", "node3"), verbose = TRUE)` instead. It avoids the need for port fwd:ing - and the verbose will give you a little bit more info too. Also, try with only one machine and focus on that.

Comment: I finally got makeCluster to semi-work, but after each process reaches 182.6 MB ram on node01, CPU usage drops to 0. Any idea why RAM usage is being limited on a 64 gb RAM machine?

Comment: future::makeClusterPSOCK also does this same behavior. I am really confused why that would be happening.